# ConversionException oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPLTZ could not be converted to java.util.Date

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I get conversion exception on runtime when try to retrieve user. May I know how to fix this?

> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-3002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
> Exception Description: The object [oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPLTZ@48e258d5], of class [class oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPLTZ], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[createdDate-->JW7S_SYS_USER.CREATED_DATE]] with descriptor [RelationalDescriptor(javaweb7sample.entity.sample.User --> [DatabaseTable(JW7S_SYS_USER)])], could not be converted to [class java.util.Date].

User table:

```
created_date TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
```

User entity:

```
@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
protected Calendar createdDate;
```

Info:

> GlassFish Server 4.1.1
>
> Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1
>
> Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0
>
> Finest:   property=eclipselink.target-server; value=SunAS9; translated
> value=org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.sunas.SunAS9ServerPlatform
> Finest:   property=eclipselink.logging.logger; value=ServerLogger
> Finest:   property=eclipselink.logging.level; value=ALL; translated
> value=ALL Finest:   property=eclipselink.logging.timestamp; value=true
> Finest:   property=eclipselink.logging.thread; value=true Finest:
> property=eclipselink.logging.session; value=true Finest:
> property=eclipselink.logging.connection; value=true Finest:
> property=eclipselink.logging.exceptions; value=true Finest:
> property=eclipselink.logging.parameters; value=true Finest:
> property=eclipselink.logging.level; value=ALL; translated value=ALL
> Finest:   property=eclipselink.logging.timestamp; value=true Finest:
> property=eclipselink.logging.thread; value=true Finest:
> property=eclipselink.logging.session; value=true Finest:
> property=eclipselink.logging.connection; value=true Finest:
> property=eclipselink.logging.exceptions; value=true Finest:
> property=eclipselink.logging.parameters; value=true Finest:
> property=eclipselink.target-database; value=oracle; translated
> value=org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform

Comment: Turn on logging to finest and check that it is using the correct database platform class when it deploys, and verify you have the correct ojdbc jar on the path as mentioned here https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/443917/

Comment: @Chris It is using OraclePlatform. Unfortunately still receive the same error with ojdbc6 and ojdbc7,

Comment: Encounter 'NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/sql/TIMESTAMP' when specify database platform as Oracle9Platform and Oracle11Platform.

Comment: If it can't find the TIMESTAMP class, you have a class loading issue - Show where this error is coming from, and maybe try putting the driver jar on the server class path.

Comment: @Chris I encounter 'NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/sql/TIMESTAMP' during deployment when eclipselink.target-database is changed to  Oracle12Platform from OraclePlatform, even added ojdbc7.jar in 'glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext' folder.

Comment: Finest:   property=eclipselink.target-database; value=org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle12Platform
Severe:   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/sql/TIMESTAMP
 at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle9Platform.<clinit>(Oracle9Platform.java:116)

Oracle12Platform is specified, but why the error is on Oracle9Platform?

Comment: Oracle12Platform extends prior version functionality. NoClassDefFoundError means the class isn't found, so you'll have to check the glassfish server docs on where it should go.